# If statement on a select box value in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am having problems writing a `function` in javascript on a PHP page that points to a select box. This if statement is to point to the select box

```
if (!(document.getElementById("add_product").value)==="Choose here")
```

Here's the code:

```
                     function promptEnrollmentMonth() {
                         if (!(document.getElementById("add_product").value)==="Choose here") {
                             var month = prompt("Is this the correct month for this course/product?", "<?php echo "$EnrollmentMonth"; ?>");
                             if (month !=null) {

                             }
                         }
                     }

 <button type="submit"
 onclick="promptEnrollmentMonth()">Update</button>

 <div>Add course/product:<select name='add_product'>
 <option selected>Choose here</option> 
 <option>Other options...</option>
 </select></div>
```

Comment: if (document.getElementById("add_product").value !=="Choose here")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo in the if statement

```
if (!(document.getElementById("add_product").value)==="Choose here")
```

should be

```
if (document.getElementById("add_product").value !=="Choose here")
```

you need to set the value to choose here for the initial option. Or

```
if (document.getElementById("add_product").value !=="")
```

this case would apply if you don't want to set a value to the initial select option.

```
!(document.getElementById("add_product").value)
```

would just translate to true or false, which would never equal "Choose here"

Answer (score 3):

First issue is with `"<?php echo "$EnrollmentMonth"; ?>"`

it should be like :

```
var month = prompt("Is this the correct month for this course/product?", "<?php echo $EnrollmentMonth; ?>");
```

Second `<option selected>Choose here</option>` you haven't provide value attribute to option tag :

```
<option value='Choose here' selected>Choose here</option>
```